# Form validation with django 1.2 GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-models, localization, django-forms

How can I add form validation and preferably with i18n localization? I tried something like the following which doesn't work and needs to import Validationerror

```
class AForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):

  def clean_name(self):
      value = self.data['name']

      if not value:
        raise ValidationError("No name.")
        return self.data['name']

  def clean_email(self):
      pass
```

If I get it to work can I raise a localized ValidationError like this?

```
ValidationError(_("No name."))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the Google app engine, so the import paths are probably wrong, but the pattern I've used before with standard Django is:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class AForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_name(self):
        # Get the value from the cleaned data.
        value = self.cleaned_data['name']

        # Check it exists.
        if not value:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("No name."))

        # Return the (now validated) value.
        return self.data['name']
```

See [the docs on field validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) for further information.

Also, I presume that your actual application is more complicated than this - if you only want to check that the field is given, set [the required attribute](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/fields/#required) on the field and Django will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm afraid it doesn't work with google app engine even though I set the required attribute. I wonder if it is implemented with GAE or why not?